# Reduce rows into json key / value pair with postgres

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql

I have a postgres table something like this.

```
+----+-----------+----------------------+--------+
| id |    Key    |        Value         | userId |
+----+-----------+----------------------+--------+
|  1 | email     | thomas@reggi.com     |      1 |
|  2 | firstName | thomas               |      1 |
|  3 | lastName  | reggi                |      1 |
|  4 | email     | new.thomas@reggi.com |      1 |
+----+-----------+----------------------+--------+
```

I'm looking for a way to "reduce" this table down to a json object.

```
{
   "email": "new.thomas@reggi.com",
   "firstName": "thomas",
   "lastName": "reggi"
}
```

How close can I get to this with just using postgres?

Answer (score 4):

If the table is called `data`, try this (`jsonb_pretty` is just for display purposes):

```
SELECT jsonb_pretty(
          jsonb_object_agg(key, value ORDER BY id)
       )
FROM data
WHERE userid = 1;

┌──────────────────────────────────────┐
│             jsonb_pretty             │
├──────────────────────────────────────┤
│ {                                   ↵│
│     "email": "new.thomas@reggi.com",↵│
│     "lastName": "reggi",            ↵│
│     "firstName": "thomas"           ↵│
│ }                                    │
└──────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

This relies on the feature that `jsonb` does not keep duplicate keys.

It also relies on the fact that `jsonb` will always retain the *last* added key/value pair.

Comment: It can be controlled, which keys to kept: `jsonb_object_agg` (just like any other aggregate function) accepts an `ORDER BY` clause, f.ex. `jsonb_object_agg(key, value ORDER BY id)` to preserve the `key` with highest `id` (the last added key-value pair will be kept)

Comment: Yes, but that means that you have to rely on an undocumented implementation detail in `jsonb`, namely that the last added pair will be kept. Maybe I am overly anxious. I'll add a few ideas to the answer to address the problem.

Comment: It [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html): *If duplicate keys are specified in the input, only the last value is kept.* -- even the `json` type have similar handling: *if a JSON object within the value contains the same key more than once, all the key/value pairs are kept. (The processing functions consider the last value as the operative one.)*

Comment: Great, thanks. I have improved the answer accorsing to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to always have the latest value for a key, you could use a `CTE` and the `RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT * FROM p;
┌────┬───────────┬──────────────────────┬────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ id │    key    │        value         │ userid │     modification_time      │
├────┼───────────┼──────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│  1 │ email     │ thomas@reggi.com     │      1 │ 2016-10-05 12:53:32.936704 │
│  2 │ firstName │ thomas               │      1 │ 2016-10-05 12:53:32.936704 │
│  3 │ lastName  │ reggi                │      1 │ 2016-10-05 12:53:32.936704 │
│  4 │ email     │ new.thomas@reggi.com │      1 │ 2016-11-06 15:53:48.025775 │
└────┴───────────┴──────────────────────┴────────┴────────────────────────────┘
(4 rows)
```

---

```
WITH info_with_rank_for_user AS (
  SELECT userId,
         modification_time,
         value,
         key,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY userId, key ORDER BY id DESC)
  FROM p
)
SELECT userId,
       json_object_agg(key, value),
       MAX(modification_time) AS last_settings_modification_time
FROM info_with_rank_for_user
WHERE rank = 1
GROUP BY userId
;
┌────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ userid │                                  json_object_agg                                   │ last_settings_modification_time │
├────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│      1 │ { "email" : "new.thomas@reggi.com", "firstName" : "thomas", "lastName" : "reggi" } │ 2016-11-06 15:53:48.025775      │
└────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: This is perfect! I have another column on my table, any idea how to get that in as well? So the columns sho up `userId, otherColumn, json_object_agg`?

Comment: @ThomasReggi: It sort of depends on what `otherColumn` represents. I added an example where it's also something you want to aggregate (here using `MAX()`). If that's not the case add it to your question, it's a bit hard to help otherwise :)